# Limiting number of duplicate labels using QGIS

Tags: qgis, road

I am using QGIS 3.10.

[image]

I am trying to draw a map of the US interstate highway.

How could I limit the number of labels to just a handful per each interestate highway?

I have tried all the various settings but haven't got the required result.

Comment: Please be a little more specific about the settings you have selected, and how they failed to provide what you need.

Comment: Have you tried to use option Labels>Rendering>Feature option>Merge connected lines to avoid duplicate labels?

Answer (score 2):

As commented go to Labels-Rendering-Feature option and check Merge connected lines:

[image]